# Avoid refreshing of Gridview when a dropdown placed in it fires a trigger - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically creating a dropdownlist and a textbox inside a gridview. The textbox is currently diabled. The IDs of both these controls are being fetched from an SQL table (so they are also dynamic in nature as the values received from SQL might change).

I want the text box to be enabled only if "Other" is selected in newly generated dropdownlist. Below is the code for dropdownlist that I am generating:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 400;
    e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[5].Width = 300;
    e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[9].Width = 300;
    string anstype = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
    string ansname = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
    string othertype = e.Row.Cells[6].Text;
    string othername = e.Row.Cells[7].Text;

    if (anstype == "DropDownList")
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = ansname;
        ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        ddl.Width = 300;
        e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(ddl);
    }

    if (othertype == "Free Text")
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = othername;
        txt.Width = 300;
        txt.Enabled = false;
        e.Row.Cells[9].Controls.Add(txt);
    }

protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlName = new DropDownList();
    ddlName = (DropDownList)sender;
    string val = ddlName.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    if (val == "Other")
    {
        //ENABLE THE TEXT BOX
    }
}
```

The simplest approach that I can think of is to pass the name of textbox (othename variable) to the eventhandler. Though being an noob with C#, I am not sure how to do it. PLEASE HELP..!!!

> **!!..EDIT..!!**

I figured out the way to refer the text but now theres another issue that I am facing. Because of the "AutoPostBack", the whole GridView get refreshed and the even for the dropdownlist doesn't get triggered. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could always have the same ID for the text box and dropdown, just prepending "textbox_" and "dropdown_" to them to keep them unique.  That way all you need do is get the ID of `sender` and chop off dropdown_ to have the ID available for finding your text box.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Never thought of that. Would work on this. Just one more question, in order to fire the event I would have to set the autopostback property of dropdownlist to TRUE. However, if I do that, the whole gridview gets refreshed and the controls displayed in the gridview just disappear :(

Comment: Is your gridview databound?  If so, make sure you rebind on each page load.  If it isn't, and there isn't a lot of data (thousands of rows, for example) then you could potentially store it in `ViewState` or `Session`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you bind data to your grid?

Comment: I am basically trying to create a survey page. The user selects a type of survey in a dropdown and clicks the "Show Survey" button. Then the corresponding questions are fetched from the database. These questions are then shown in the first column of the gridview. The control for answer (text box, dropdownlist, radiobutton) is then generated dynamically against every question. I am successful till this part. IF user selects "Other" as an answer then a secondary control should be presented to user to provide details. This is the part I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments given so far, if I may summarise, you have a set of questions for a survey being loaded out of your database.  You want people to select answers from controls you then generate server-side against these questions.  That's all straight-forward so far, but where it gets complicated is that you want a textbox to appear when they select 'Other' from an answer drop-down, and to get the rest of their response in that box.  If you try to do this server-side, since the controls aren't part of your gridview's column definition normally, they all disappear and you lose your answers.

Why not try always having the textbox there, and setting its [CSS visibility property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) through javascript instead?  A sample function (sourced from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/86493/how-to-make-controls-visible-false-using-javascript)) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleVisibility(controlId)
    {
        var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
        if(control.style.visibility == "visible" || control.style.visibility == "")
            control.style.visibility = "hidden";
        else 
            control.style.visibility = "visible";

    }
</script>
```

So you would instead bind a call to this function (or a wrapper function) in the drop-down's `Click` event and always have the textbox on the page, just hidden.  That way you don't need to post-back until all their answers are done and submitted.

Comment: Thanks Adrian..!! Though (I am sorry for this creep) the number of questions are not static as well.. So for one user I may have 20 questions but for other I may have 120 questions. Also there is not set max limit for the number of questions. Somebody suggested me to use create a static table inside a Repeater control. I googled for Repeater but things went flying over my head :p